# how to make a horizontal list of color palette in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to implement the below design. But after looking at this I think there will be a lot of `view` that has to be created inside a vertical `LinearLayout` which is lot of copy paste. Can anyone tell me a better way of creating this type of design?

[image]

Comment: how about using a `Recyclerview`

Comment: Have you tried this library, https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1882 It may helps you

Comment: If you want to create this by yourself only, you can create this programmatically in your .java/.kt file , can use array/`ArrayList` to hold the color's hexCode & use loop for creating the Views OR use horizontal `RecyclerView`

Comment: @NileshRathod I think it sounds good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this will work for you.

Create like  `onCreate()` method of your Activity given below.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        HorizontalScrollView scrollView = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

        int[] colorArray = {Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK, Color.parseColor("#ff00ff"), Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK, Color.parseColor("#ff00ff"), Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK, Color.parseColor("#ff00ff"), Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK, Color.parseColor("#ff00ff"), Color.RED, Color.GRAY, Color.BLACK, Color.parseColor("#ff00ff")};

        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

        setContentView(scrollView);

        linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        scrollView.addView(linearLayout);

        scrollView.setFillViewport(true);


        for (int i = 0; i < colorArray.length; i++) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setBackgroundColor(colorArray[i]);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(140, 200));
            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }

    }
```

take an array of your color code in hex format.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `RecyclerView` and init an `adapter` with colors to display it. Use `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` to scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Use a RecyclerView and add a LinearLayout with the orientation horizontal

```
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
```